# How to solve npm error "npm ERR! errno -4058" "nom ERR! enoent"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

js to use react and created "npx create-react-app delivery" in Visual Studio Code. By the way, I keep getting npm errors. How can this be resolved?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! C:\Users\***\Documents\React class
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-04T03_51_11_010Z-debug.log
```

My environment setting is below:
node.js: 16.12.0 LTS
OS: window 10

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is a space symbol in your project folder name. Just rename it without spaces

Comment: thank you for answering! I changed the folder name without spaces, but I'm still getting the error...

Comment: Did you remove spaces from all folders in a path to your project?